# Update User and Group attributes using Azure java sdk

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-management-api

I'm following [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aad-java-manage-users-groups-and-roles) example to create a JAVA class to manage Azure AD Users and Groups.
It uses the following library:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I did not find a way to **update** some `User` and `Group` attributes (like `displayName` or `mailNickname` for Users and `displayName` for Groups).

I see that I can do something like this:

```
user = client.getAuthenticated().activeDirectoryUsers()
       .getByName(uid.getUidValue());
user.update()
   .withPassword(accessor.getPassword().toString())
   .apply();
```

but actually I can't change other attributes.

Any help with that please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you want to update Azure AD Graph Users & Groups via [Microsoft Azure SDK For Graph RBAC Management](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-graph-rbac) `com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac`. I reviewed the current [javadocs](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/graphrbac/package-frame.html) of Azure Graph RBAC Management, it seems to not support these attributes update operations you want now.

So by now, the effective way is directly using the Azure AD Graph APIs, please refer to the offical [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) to know how to use it. And there is an offical code sample [active-directory-java-graphapi-web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-graphapi-web) that you can refer to.

Hope it helps.